# How do you calculate the number of tokens that are worth 1 eth before swapping in Uniswap pool?

Tags: contract-development, uniswap

I want to make a function for my token contract that allows me to swap a dynamic amount of tokens in exchange for 1 eth.

Is it possible to calculate how many tokens are worth 1 eth and then swap with Uniswap V2 to get exactly that amount of eth out?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work? Calling UniswapV2's [getAmountsOut](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/library#getamountsout).

In the example below I'm using the Uni token contract address for the token on Goerli: [0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984](https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenSwap {

    address private constant TOKEN_ADDRESS = 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984; // Uni token on Goerli
    address private constant ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D; // Uniswap V2 router
    
    IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswapRouter;
    IERC20 private token;

    constructor() {
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(ROUTER_ADDRESS);
        token = IERC20(TOKEN_ADDRESS);
    }

    function swapTokens() external payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether, "Must send exactly 1 ETH");
        
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
        path[1] = TOKEN_ADDRESS;
        
        uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(msg.value, path);
        uint256 amountOut = amounts[1]; // Amount of tokens for 1 ETH through Uniswap V2
        
        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15;
        uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: msg.value }(amountOut, path, msg.sender, deadline);
        
        // Refund remaining ETH to user
        if (address(this).balance > 0) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Here's an example deployment on Goerli: [0x9ef84b761224d95B46d39D972499eDe90Af54ead](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x9ef84b761224d95b46d39d972499ede90af54ead)

Answer (score 0):

The router function is called getAmountIn. You can incorporate the calculation in or just call it from your tax-on-transfer contract.

```js
    // given an output amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns a required input amount of the other asset
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountIn) {
        require(amountOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint numerator = reserveIn.mul(amountOut).mul(1000);
        uint denominator = reserveOut.sub(amountOut).mul(997);
        amountIn = (numerator / denominator).add(1);
```

We use getAmountIn, since we know the output amount, and want the amount needed in for that exact amount out.